# Mapear uma entidade no java chave primaria composta?

Tags: java, spring, classes, boot, entidade

Como mapear no java uma entidade com outra tabela utilizando chave primaria composta?

Tabela1
Id-primary key
Nome

Tabela2
Id-primary key
Seq-primary key
Descricao

preciso montar a entidade tabela1 e buscar na tabela2.

segue como estou fazendo mas esta dando erro:

agradeço desde de já.
entidade tabela1

```java
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn( name=id)
private List<Tabela2> lista;
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que eu entendi, você deseja montar um relacionamento um para muitos e através da tabela 1 (Autor) carregar os dados da tabela 2 (livro) usando somente a consulta da tabela 1.

```
@Entity
public class Autor {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String nome;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "autor")
   @JsonManagedReference(value = "autor-livros")
   private List<Livro> livros;
}

@Entity
public class Livro {
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String titulo;
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "autor_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_livro_autor"))
   @JsonBackReference(value = "autor-livros")
   private Autor autor;
}
```